# Poetry install throws "Connection pool is full, discarding connection: pypi.org. Connection pool size: 10" error when building Docker image

Tags: docker, pypi, python-poetry

I cannot build my docker image. It throws "Connection is full" error when installing dependencies via Poetry. This does not happen on my host machine. How can I solve this. Do I need to increase the pool size? If yes, how?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine AS python
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
WORKDIR /app

FROM python as poetry
ENV POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry
ENV POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$PATH"
RUN python -c 'from urllib.request import urlopen; print(urlopen("https://install.python-poetry.org").read().decode())' | python -
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi -vvv
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using your Dockerfile with my project I added a line before the last one as follows:

```
RUN poetry config installer.max-workers 10

RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi -vvv
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Docs https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/configuration/#installermax-workers says the default value is "Default: number_of_cores + 4" and it is the max value