# "Connection pool is full, discarding connection: foo.bar.com Connection pool size: 10" during poetry install

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a function which handles the creation of the virtual environment of my project using poetry as follows:

```py
def generate_venv():

  # Create first venv and install poetry in it
  venv.create(env_dir="/path/to/poetry/venv", with_pip=True)
  subprocess.run(check=True, args=["/path/to/poetry/venv/bin/pip", "install", "poetry"], capture_output=True)

  # Let poetry create my project venv and install its dependencies
  subprocess.run(check=True, args=["/path/to/poetry/venv/bin/poetry", "install"])
```

Everything works well. The only issue is that I get the following warning:

`Connection pool is full, discarding connection: foo.bar.com Connection pool size: 10`

I am aware of the [installer.max-workers config](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#installermax-workers) of poetry, and as suggests it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385209/poetry-install-throws-connection-pool-is-full-discarding-connection-pypi-org), setting that config to 10 solves indeed the problem. However, I would rather increase the size of the connectionpool or just find a way to suppress the warning instead of limiting the number of workers poetry uses and stunting performance.

I haven't found a way to increase the connection maxpoolsize used by Poetry since I haven't found a way to get the connection pool which poetry uses.
So I tried to suppress the warning instead using the PYTHONWARNINGS environment variable, but none of the following ways worked (the installation of the venv carries out well, but the warning is still present):

1. ignoring all warnings from the urllib3 module:

```py
install_environ = os.environ.copy()
install_environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore:::.*urllib3.*"
subprocess.run(check=True, args=["/path/to/poetry/venv/bin/poetry", "install"], env=install_environ)
```

2. ignoring the exact warning by matching its message:

```py
install_environ = os.environ.copy()
install_environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore:Connection pool is full"
subprocess.run(check=True, args=["/path/to/poetry/venv/bin/poetry", "install"], env=install_environ)
```

I also tried these same two strategies using the -W option of python as such:

1. `subprocess.run(check=True, args=["/path/to/poetry/venv/bin/python", "-W", "ignore:Connection pool is full", "-m", "poetry", "install"])`
2. `subprocess.run(check=True, args=["/path/to/poetry/venv/bin/python", "-W", "ignore:::.*urllib3.*", "-m", "poetry", "install"])`